# How to keep dynamic views focused through an orientation change in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-layout, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity with an EditText on top and a ScrollView with a LinearLayout inside it.

The LinearLayout is populated in the onCreate method with a set of dynamic views based on an object passed with the initiating Intent.  This is typically a set of EditTexts.

The result is a list of EditTexts each corresponding to a different piece of data (and the dataset being edited is quite variable, so the list needs to be created dynamically like this).

The problem is, when one of these views has focus, and the orientation changes (say the user flips out the keyboard to type), the focus snaps to the EditText at the very top of the Activity.  This is certainly undesired behavior as the user didn't intend to type in the top EditText when he/she flipped out the keyboard.

How can I dynamically create my list of views like this and not have this undesirable focus changing behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to assign a unique and consistent id to each of my dynamic EditTexts.

The reason the activity couldn't retain focus properly is it had no way of relocating the view because it had no id.

Answer (score -1):

When an orientation change occurs, `onDestroy()` is called, and the activity will be created again using `onCreate()`. That's why the focus is snapped at the first EditText that it finds.

You might want to have a look at this: [Handling Runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Specifically, this topic: [Retain an object during configuration change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainAnObject)

Comment: Yes, I understand the basics of lifecycle. But without my dynamic views, focus is retained by the activity automatically. I'm trying to understand why that behavior doesn't apply to my dynamic views and how to mimic it.